# Считывание слов из файла в массив

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Есть файл, в котором на каждой строке записано по слову. Нужно считать их в массив. Количество слов и их длина заранее неизвестна. Компилируется с ошибками при выводе слов на экран. Что необходимо изменить?
Вот фрагмент кода.

```
   char** Startwords = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
   char** Startaddwords;
   char* Startstring = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   char* Startaddstring;
   char c;
   int count = 0;
   c = getc(Swords);
   while (c != EOF)
   {
       count++;
       int size = 1;
       while (c != EOF)
       {
           Startaddstring = (char*)realloc(Startstring, size*sizeof(char));
           if (Startaddstring != NULL)
           {
               Startstring = Startaddstring;
               if (c != '\n')
               {
                   Startstring[size - 1] = c;
                   c = getc(Swords);
                   size++;
               }
               else
               {
                   Startstring[size - 1] = '\0';
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       Startaddwords = (char**)realloc(Startwords, (count) * sizeof(char*));
       if (Startaddwords != NULL)
       {
           Startwords = Startaddwords;
           Startwords[count - 1] = Startstring;
           Startstring = NULL;
           c = getc(Swords);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте fscanf  - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

По теме алокации памяти для хранения - есть много дорог тут:

1. указать максмум
2. реалоцироваться в лоб каждый раз при добавлении
3. реалацироваться по умному (прикапывая 5% от общего объема) но нужно заводить структуру и прикапывать это.
   и еще тьма вариантов

Вам выбирать какой дорогой идти

Вот пример в лоб:

#include<stdio.h>

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int MAX_WORD = 512;

char* strdump(char* line) {
  int alloc_size = strlen(line) + 1;
  char* buf = (char*)malloc(alloc_size);
  strncpy(buf, line, alloc_size);
  buf[alloc_size - 1] = '\0';

  return buf;
}

char** ReadFileWordByWord(FILE* _file) {
  char buf[256];

  char** arr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * MAX_WORD);
  if (arr == NULL) {
    return arr;
  }
  
  unsigned int index = 0;

  while (fscanf(_file, "%255s", buf) == 1 && index < MAX_WORD) {
    arr[index] = strdump(buf);
    ++index;
  }
  if (index < MAX_WORD) {
    arr[index] = NULL;
  }

  return arr;
}

FILE* OpenFile(char* _filename) {
  FILE* _file;
  _file = fopen("data", "r");
  if (_file == NULL) {
    perror("Failed: ");
  }

  return _file;
}

void PrintAndClean(char** arr) {
  unsigned int index = 0;
  while (arr[index] != NULL && index < MAX_WORD) {
    puts(arr[index]);
    free(arr[index]);
    ++index;
  }
  free(arr);
}

int main() {
  FILE* _file;
  _file = OpenFile("data");
  if (_file == NULL) {
    return 1;
  }

  char** arr = ReadFileWordByWord(_file);
  if (arr == NULL) {
    return 2;
  }

  fclose(_file);

  PrintAndClean(arr);

  return 0;
}
```